# Looping through a second array inside of a filter function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble looping through the array `tabData` that's inside of a `filter` array function. Any suggestions?

This is my current line of code

```
const filteredData = allData.filter(({ existingLabel }) => existingLabel === tabData[/* Im having trouble iterating through this array  */].label);
```

**Structure of array `allData`**

```
0: {existingLabel: "exams", x: "xyz", a:12345, ...many fields}
1: {existingLabel: "notes", x: "ska", a:67333, ...many fields}
2: {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "sf3", a:34355, ...many fields}
3: {existingLabel: "notes", x: "xhi", a:34253, ...many fields}
4: {existingLabel: "exams", x: "ojk", a:98527, ...many fields}
5: {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "qid", a:65287, ...many fields}
```

**Structure of array `tabData`**

```
0:{tab:1 , label:'notes'} 
1:{tab:2 , label:'exams'}
2:{tab:3 , label:'quiz'}
```

> I tried doing the following, but I get this error 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'

```
 const filteredData = allData.filter(({ existingLabel }) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < tabData.length(); i++) {
        existingLabel === tabData[i].label;
    }
});
```

Comment: What are you looking for? Are you seeing if `existingLabel` matches all of `tabData.label` or just one? In which case check out [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Im trying to match each index in allData to a label category in tabData @Aplet123

Comment: What do you mean by match? You're filtering the array. Do you mean if `existingLabel` is equal to at least one label in `tabData` it doesn't get filtered out?

Comment: yeah, I just want to loop through that array...I feel like its straight forward but I'm having a difficult time since its inside a filter function

Comment: Can you provide an expected output

Comment: the expected output would be that im able to loop through tabData. @AniketG Im just trying to compare two fields 'label' and 'existingLabel'

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a one liner. Although if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, I can provide a loophole. I need to see your expected output though

Comment: expected output: When on tab 1, I expect filteredData to only contain fields that have 'notes' as the label. When on tab 2 should only contain fields that have 'exams' as the label.  When I manually enter the tab for example if I do existingLabel === tabData[3].label;  filteredData will only contain fields that have 'quiz' as the label, but instead of entering it manually im looking to loop through the array. @AniketG

Comment: Then you're missing a variable somewhere.  What is it that tracks "when on tab N"?  It's easy enough to write a function for this when supplied the label of the current tab, but without it, your question is not specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Thank you for the help everyone :) This is how I solved my problem

```
const filteredData = allData.filter(({ existingLabel }) => {
            let returnedData = [];
            for (let i = 1; i < tabData.length; i++) {
                if (tab === i) {
                    returnedData = existingLabel === tabData[i].label;
                }
            }
            return returnedData;
});

const finalData = tab === 0 ? allData : filteredData;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to solve your problem. As this code loops through `allData`, it checks if the tab of the current element is equal to the specified tab. If it is, it keeps it. If it isn't, it removes it.

```js
let allData = [{existingLabel: "exams", x: "xyz", a:12345}, {existingLabel: "notes", x: "ska", a:67333}, {existingLabel: "quiz", x: "sf3", a:34355}, {existingLabel: "notes", x: "xhi", a:34253}, {existingLabel: "exams", x: "ojk", a:98527}, {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "qid", a:65287}];
let tabData = [{tab:1 , label:'notes'}, {tab:2 , label:'exams'}, {tab:3 , label:'quiz'}];
let tab = 2;

const filteredData = allData.filter(({ existingLabel }) => tabData.filter(e => e.label == existingLabel)[0].tab == tab);

console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the information currently supplied, this is impossible.  But with one additional piece of information, this is straightforward.  If you already know the label of the tab you're looking for, you can do this:

```js
const filterToLabel = (allData) => (tabLabel) => 
  allData.filter(({existingLabel}) => existingLabel === tabLabel)

const allData = [{existingLabel: "exams", x: "xyz", a:12345}, {existingLabel: "notes", x: "ska", a:67333}, {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "sf3", a:34355}, {existingLabel: "notes", x: "xhi", a:34253}, {existingLabel: "exams", x: "ojk", a:98527}, {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "qid", a:65287}]
const tabData = [{tab:1 , label:'notes'}, {tab:2 , label:'exams'}, {tab:3 , label:'quiz'}]

console.log(filterToLabel(allData)('notes')) //=> ska/67333, xhi/34253
```

If you don't know the label, but know the tab number, this is almost as simple:

```js
const filterToTabId = (allData, tabData) => (tabId) => {
  const tab = tabData.find(({tab}) => tab == tabId)
  // if (!tab) // throw error or return empty array
  return allData.filter(({existingLabel}) => existingLabel === tab.label)
}

const allData = [{existingLabel: "exams", x: "xyz", a:12345}, {existingLabel: "notes", x: "ska", a:67333}, {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "sf3", a:34355}, {existingLabel: "notes", x: "xhi", a:34253}, {existingLabel: "exams", x: "ojk", a:98527}, {existingLabel: "quiz",  x: "qid", a:65287}]
const tabData = [{tab:1 , label:'notes'}, {tab:2 , label:'exams'}, {tab:3 , label:'quiz'}]

console.log(filterToTabId(allData, tabData)(2)) //=> xyz/1234, ojk/98527
```

And you could do something similar if you know the index in the array of the current tab.